# LVM error Device not found (or ignored by filtering) but no partitions exist on device

Tags: lvm

I've deleted all partitions on 2 local disks and am setting up LVM across these two disks. I have successfully created a physical volume on `/dev/sda`, but doing so on `/dev/sdb` fails as described below. I'm working from a linux mint USB installer (e.g. neither disk is mounted).

Attempting to create a physical volume:

```
mint ~ # pvcreate /dev/sdb
  Device /dev/sdb not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

Verify that there are no partitions

```
mint ~ # fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 785CAD57-8930-43D2-A61E-572453B74805

Command (m for help): q
```

Look at `/proc/partitions` - this was requested in a troubleshooting guide I attempted to follow.

```
mint ~ # cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   7        0    1799560 loop0
   8        0  125034840 sda
   8       16  976762584 sdb
   8       32    1966080 sdc
   8       33    1966030 sdc1
```

---

Added detail from comments:

No output from:

```
grep -n '^[^#]*filter' /etc/lvm/lvm*.conf
```

Strace result from near the error message (the output was very long):

```
strace pvcreate /dev/sdb

stat("/dev/sdb", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(8, 16), ...}) = 0
open("/dev/sdb", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECT|O_NOATIME) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(8, 16), ...}) = 0
ioctl(4, BLKBSZGET, [4096])             = 0
ioctl(4, BLKPBSZGET, [512])             = 0
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
close(4)                                = 0
write(2, "  ", 2  )                       = 2
write(2, "Device /dev/sdb not found (or ig"..., 52Device /dev/sdb not found (or ignored by filtering).) = 52
```

Comment: What is the output of `grep -n '^[^#]*filter' /etc/lvm/lvm*.conf`?

Comment: No output from that.

Comment: You could run `pvcreate /dev/sdb` through `strace`. That would tell you if `pvcreate` tried to access `sdb`.

Comment: Added, I see a call to `stat`, and `open` on `/dev/sdb` followed shortly after by `write` with the error message. It looks like open resulted in 4, which might be `#define EINTR            4      /* Interrupted system call */` based on this page: http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html

Comment: The return value for `open()` is the file descriptor which is used in the following syscalls. I am surprised. Accessing `sdb` is obviously not a problem but why should it even be tried if the device has been blacklisted...

Comment: I can create and delete partitions, doing so made no difference. Also tried a reboot without change.

Comment: @ Hauke Langing, thanks very much for the help. I've posted the solution I just found in some documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer while going through some documentation in detail:

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/physvol_create.html

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```

From the documentation referenced above:

> **4.2.1.1. Setting the Partition Type**
>
> If you are using a whole disk device for your physical volume, the
>   disk must have no partition table. For DOS disk partitions, the
>   partition id should be set to 0x8e using the fdisk or cfdisk command
>   or an equivalent. For whole disk devices only the partition table must
>   be erased, which will effectively destroy all data on that disk. You
>   can remove an existing partition table by zeroing the first sector
>   with the following command:

After running that command I was able to create the physical volume.

Comment: thank you, that solved my pb

Comment: If `pvcreate` is run with `-vvv` you might also see: `Device /dev/sdb excluded by a filter. No devices to process.`. In my case, I'd already run the above `dd` command, but it turned out I needed to overwrite with some more zeroes: `bs=4096k count=100`.